# Fetching nested objects with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to fetch nested objects but not quite sure how to achieve this. My model is as shown:

```
class Brand(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Size(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Brand_Size(models.Model)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)

class Brand_Size_Location(models.Model)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    brand_size = models.ForeignKey(Brand_Size)
```

I filter objects in `Brand_Size_Location` by location which can occur `1..x`. I want my serializer to output the results in terms of the model `Brand` (BrandSerializer). Since my resultset can be `1..x` and furthermore the occurrence of `Brand` can be duplicates i would like to eliminate these aswell at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easily by including a serializer field in your BrandSerializer:

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_sizes = BrandSizeSerializer(
        source='brand_size_set',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = (
            'id',
            ...add more fields you want here
            'brand_sizes')
```

You can simlarly create the brand size serializer to nest the locations

Filtering on this relationship occurs in the view and will need a custom filter. Here's a basic example using a `ListView`:

```
class BrandFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    location = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Brand_Size_Location.objects.all(),
        name='brand_size__brand_size_location__location'
    )
    location_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name='brand_size__brand_size_location__location__name'
    )

class Meta:
    model = Brand
    fields = [
        'location',
        'location_name'
    ]
```

class BrandList(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Brand
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
    filter_class = BrandFilter

You can then use query parameters to filter on the URL like:

```
http://somehost/api/brands/?location=42
```

which uses a PK to filter, or with the location name (assuming you have a name field in the Location model):

```
http://somehost/api/brands/?location_name=Atlantis
```

Comment: So the result i get from filtering objects in  `Brand_Size_Location` i simply serialize with `BrandSerializer`? Or how is this done in practice..

Comment: @JavaCake Not sure if I'm following completely, but filtering isn't done in the serializer, but in the view. To filter on a nested relationship will require writing a custom filter, which is quite easy actually...I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: Im sorry for misleading you with my question. Basically what i mean is, can i take the resultset from my filtering of `Brand_Size_Location` and apply the serializer to it (`BrandSerializer`)?

Comment: Ahh, so you are using `Brand_Size_Location` as the model for the view, and want to have a nested `Brand` field with it's own nested info?

Comment: Exactly. The filtering is occuring on the `Brand_Size_Location` model. Where i become a little confused is how to serialize it so _deep_. I attempted to mess around with `depth` but i did not exactly get what i wanted. So what i want is to take my resultset from the filtering, get  all `Brand_Size` followed by `Brand` where i eliminate the duplicates. So basically i will end up with a list of `Brand` items.

Comment: I see, you'll want to override `get_queryset` in the `Brand_Size_Location` ListView to accomplish that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51031/discussion-between-fiver-and-javacake)

Comment: I never came with a good solution to how i should create this list of `Brand` items which are unique as we discussed. Looks like i will end up with for-loops and arrays?

Comment: Can you simplify your models by eliminating `Brand_Size` and including the `brand` and `size` fields in the `Brand_Size_Location` model?

Comment: To begin with it should have been eliminated, but it serves multiple purposes and hence kept as a reference table. Not sure if it makes sense?

Comment: I actually ended up moving the `Brand_Size` fields to `Brand_Size_Location`. But im still not sure how to solve the primary problem? If i use `depth` i get all the columns, which im not interested in.